# Nginx "ngx_http_geoip_module.so" error on nginx -t

Tags: nginx, centos7

I am trying to setup Nginx on my CentOS 7 VPS, I have installed Nginx, MariaDb and PHP.

But when I run `nginx -t` I get:

```
nginx: [emerg] module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so" version 1012002 instead of 1014000 in /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-http-geoip.conf:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Why is this happening? I haven't even touched anything `ngx_http_geoip_module.so` related.

**Version Information**

Nginx version:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.14.0
built by gcc 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16) (GCC)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib64/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-compat --with-file-aio --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream --with-stream_realip_module --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie'
```

CentOS version:

```
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
```

Comment: I had the same problem, seems like a package management issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is what I did to fix this.

`yum remove nginx`

I then re-installed it by doing:

`yum install nginx`

And now when I did `nginx -t` I got:

> nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Answer (score 10):

I had nginx 1.12 installed and updated to 1.16 using [this link](https://codybonney.com/install-the-latest-version-of-nginx-on-centos-6-and-centos-7-using-yum/)

Then I encountered to the same error. Removing old module files using this command solved my problem.

```
sudo yum remove nginx-mod*
```

Comment: omg thank you so much